# Is there a bug using lens rectangle in xzoom jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins, frontend, internet-explorer-11, web-frontend

I'm using [jquery xzoom plugin](https://payalord.github.io/xZoom/) in my application.
In Chrome works fine but doesn't in IE 11.
With lens by default (rectangle) the main image is shown displaced behind the lens in y axes (displaced vertically) when src of image is base64 data, not if src referencing to image like .jpg image.
I think it is maybe because main image width is modified before it is rendered, but in Chrome works fine like I said
Anyone can help me please?

Comment: If only based on your description, I am afraid I cannot determine the cause of the problem. Could you provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Are there any error messages in the IE devTools console?

Comment: Thank you @Xudong Peng, yo are right.
However, I found a solution. Adding an AngularJS $timeout() function that wraps 
 xzoom solved it. For example
`$timeout(function(){
 $('#main_source").xzoom({ tint: '#fff', Xoffset: 5});
}, 0);`

Comment: I am glad you have solved the problem, you can post it as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.